# Retrieve details by transaction_id after submission gravity froms

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, hook, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using Gravity Forms for payment section on my website. Once I fill all the data and submit the form, It passing the values to Paypal. After payments completed, It redirects to my website again. What I need is, I should show the user details and payment details on this page if payment status is success. I can get the transection_id by GET method.

```
$transection_id = $_GET['st'];
```

How can I get the details by using this $transection_id. Already the details are in the database now. I don't no how to query database. Can I use hooks for this?

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_5", "after_submission", 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the payment process it will return to the defined return URL. And we can see all the transaction details on the query string, so easily it can be request using GET method.
[paypal transaction return](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_searchRetrieveTransactionData-curl-etc/)

```
$transection_status = $_GET['st'];
$transection_amount = $_GET['su'];
```